# extjs 4.2.1 examples not showing up internet browsers

Tags: extjs

I downloaded examples from EXT JS but when I open index.html with Firefox, Internet Explorer and even Chrome; I get a blank screen. Did I forget to download something?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have downloaded the GPL version of ExtJS and have extracted it to your doc root on a web server?

Comment: If that is how your web server is configured...then yes.  What error do you get in Chrome developer tools console?

Comment: 2 errors

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < api.php:1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isProvider' of undefined

Comment: I downloaded Ext Direct and Grid part 2 from Sencha docs onto my local drive, and tried opening it but nothing shows.

Comment: You need the full extjs package and extract that to your web root.  The examples are all there.  Get the GPL version   http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/download/

Comment: That's the problem, I already downloaded, unzipped and moved it to that htdocs (that's the web root, right?), and it still doesn't work.

Comment: The examples in there work but not external examples like https://github.com/loiane

Comment: Those external examples have nothing to do with sencha examples.  Many of them are written in Ext 3.x and don't include the Ext sources...so of course they wouldn't work.  Also many of them have other dependencies like spring framework, java serverlet hosting, etc.